# Error on setting "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime

Tags: grails, jodatime, sessionfactory, transactionmanager

I am new on Grails (2.4.1). I am trying to use joda time (1.5). When I put the script below to my Config.groovy an error occurrs.

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate, class: org.joda.time.LocalDate
    // … define as many other user type mappings as you need
}
```

> error: Error | 2014-07-12 23:45:31,632 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the
>   application: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor Message: Error creating bean
>   with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor

etc.

Comment: The error is raised in line 4...

Comment: If you change your project to use Hibernate 3 instead of 4 does it work?

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your response!
I changed the hibernate version, but the error yet occurrs.
Please, see it:
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"  // ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" 

error:
etc... etc... (the same of the last post) and:
Caused by HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]... etc....

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the same error by upgrading the Jadira Usertype library dependency that the plugin was using.

The Joda Time plugin recommends "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9", which only works for Hibernate 3. Try switching to "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA" when using Hibernate 4.

Comment: For me with Grails 2.4.3 with hibernate4 the newer 2.0 version of org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0 works fine.

Comment: Grails 2.5.4  with  plugin, runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" , and dependency, compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA", is working for me.